# How to create a row of elements of equal width inside an inline container? Possibly using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a row of elements with the following features:

1. Are inside an inline-block container (which needs to have content next to it)
2. Are all the same width
3. Are auto-sized to be wide enough to contain the widest element without it overflowing
4. Are auto-sized to be narrow enough to *just* contain the widest element without it overflowing

My current efforts are using flexbox and haven't been able to fulfil all of these conditions. My latest attempt (tested in Chrome so far) is below but condition 3 is not met.

Is there something I'm missing? Or is there an alternative approach that might work?

[live example](http://jsbin.com/riwadume/1/edit?html,output)

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <A href="/">foo</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <A href="/">barrrrrrrrr</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <A href="/">foooooooooooo</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <A href="/">foo</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <A href="/">hello&nbsp;world</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(I'm not using browser compatibility vendor-prefixed versions for this test, so you might have to select a browser with good flexbox support).

Comment: It looks like you have competing requirements. CSS is not , probably going to solve this one...Js/JQ would probably be required.

Comment: I suspect there might not be a CSS solution, but the requirements don't compete. The boxes just need to be the same size and as small as the largest content.

Comment: Doubt it...you need all elements to be the same size and that would have to be computed and fed back to already rendered elements. Pretty sure that's a JS/JQ issue...I very much doubt if even flexbox could solve that.

Comment: Interestingly, even with newer width values like `min-width: -webkit-min-content;` they still won't size correctly. If you switch the flex-flow to column, they do become the correct width (albeit wrong orientation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using `display: inline-grid` on the parent element and then adding the property `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` to the parent as well (`1fr` per column needed).

```css
div.inline {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

div.cell {
    border: 1px dotted grey;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
content
<div class='inline'>
    <div class='cell'>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class='cell'>lorem</div>
</div>
content
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative would be to use `display:table` with `table-layout:fixed`, then setting the width of the underlying cells to `1%` forces the browser into using an algorithm to use equal widths for all cells.

```css
div.inline {
    display:inline-block;
    width:250px;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    width: 1%;
}
```

```html
content
<div class='inline'>
    <div class='table'>
        <div class='cell'>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class='cell'>lorem</div>
    </div>
</div>
content
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good approach, but [when I try it](http://jsbin.com/riwadume/3/edit?html,output), it stretches the `inline-block` container to 100% so I can't put anything next to it, which defeats the purposes of having it as `inline-block`. I've made that requirement more explicit in the question.

Comment: You need to either specify a width for the inline block container, or change the width of the table element -in order for it to display inline a width needs to be defined.

Comment: That requires me to know what the width should be in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Would this be an acceptable solution?

If the area for the inline block is wide enough it ticks all your points, if it's not wide enough then it fails 2.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul { 
    display: table; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center

  }
  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    border: solid black 1px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div>
<ul>
  <li><A href="/">foo</a></li>
  <li><A href="/">barrrrrrrrr</a></li>
  <li><A href="/">foooooooooooo</a></li>
  <li><A href="/">foo</a></li>
  <li><A href="/">hello&nbsp;world</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```